# Set the Dimensions of a Video

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

I was creating this sites which is to show the users videos of various games and I stumpled upon a problem. Now this is something I really can't solve, I've searched the internet, but with no success... If I would set the width and the height of a video element it's not always so that the dimensions of the movie/video will be the very same. So I only entered the width of it and hoped that the height would fix itself, which it did. However after some more editing on my page the height wasn't the value it was before. It had now changed to the pixels of the width. I tried to remove all recent actions that could have caused it and I even removed other stuff that could have done this, but with no succes. I also tried this on IE and there it worked perfectly just like it did before on my previous web browser, Chrome. So why's that? And how can I fix this? I've also tried clearing my cache and restarting my PC, but with no result...

Normal:
...........
VIDEO
...........

What it's like right now in Chrome ("||" is free space created by the video element):
|||||||||||||||
...........
VIDEO
...........
|||||||||||||||

HTML (with PHP):

```
<video poster="dasdsadsakaslmklda.jpg" id="video_video_video" controls>
                              <source src="videos/'.$id.'.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>
```

CSS:

```
.video_video video{
    width:294px;
    /*height:390px;*/
}
```

**EDIT:**
When it's loading it's all as it should be... However even though I've removed all recent codes it still renders the same incorrect way after the page has finished loading. How do I know this? Well I added a code of both Js and JQuery that were to change the dimensions and then it worked perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? You can use Chrome's developer tools to see the HTML and CSS that it's loading. If it's not the same code that's in your current file, then it's getting the file from the cache and will use an earlier version of it. You can clear it in settings.

Comment: Yes I have tried clearing my cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have been something with the cache, however it did not work at first after clearing my cache. After a couple of reboots it finally worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Would it only be a typo?

In the CSS, there's a space instead of an underscore (video_video video) compared to the id (video_video_video).

Comment: No, the class is for defining its parent and then the video inside it which is this video element. The video element is defining an ID which is for a javascript.